# How do I edit a .PDF file while its a resource?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, itext

I've been looking around on the web for an answer to a perplexing problem. I'm trying to code a program in C# and I'm looking for a snippet of code that'll take any information a user would input, i.e using a textbox or a check box, and transfer said information onto a .PDF file that I've added as a resource.

Right now I'm using Visual Studio 2008 for my coding, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did I understand correctly? After the user enters the data, it is again stored inside the exe and nowhere else (e.g. a separate PDF file)?

Comment: The idea is that as the user inputs the data, it'll be transferred onto the PDF file and saved as the user enters it. Though I'll add an undo feature in case the user makes a mistake of some kind.

Comment: So the result is a separate PDF file? The question sounds a bit confusing as it looks like you want to edit it *while* it is a resource.

Comment: Well, that's what I want to _try_ to do, but if there's another way, i'm all ears.

Comment: Can you edit your question and be more specific?

Answer (score 2):

You can use librairies to create PDF on the fly:

- [ITextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)

Answer (score 1):

PDF's are a proprietary format. PDF4Net is a pretty good library for merging information via XDF into PDF's, but you are going to have a lot of trouble trying to do this on your own natively.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I might try that.

Comment: i've used the various PDF4Net libraries pretty extensively for a past project, where I had to merge data gathered via a wpf app with bank forms, as well as generating 2D barcodes programmatically and placing them as well. it worked pretty flawlessly. the only hitch is that PDF4Net uses .NET printing inherently, which means if you attempt to print a pdf using their libraries it will convert the file to an image first. just something to be aware of depending on how many forms you need to print at once. (ie. if you try to print an 18 page doc over a network it will be S.L.O.W.)

Comment: PDF is NOT a proprietary format. It has been published as an ISO standard for many years; the specification for PDF 2.0 aka ISO-32000-2 will be available soon.

Comment: it is an Adobe proprietary format that Adobe releases for the general publics consumption. either way, you'd be nuts to try to write some kind of pdf parser/merge util for something basic like this. if you know the names of the fields, it should be relatively trivial to generate an XDF document and merge it with your PDF resource